# Xamarin.Forms WSDL import : System.ServiceModel reference

Tags: c#, wsdl, xamarin.forms

I have a private WSDL url and i want to import this url in my PCL Xamarin.Forms.

I openned my CMD and created my file with the SLSVCUTIL.

But now, when i import my file in my project, Visual Studio say: (example with w3c)

[image]

And if i add the System.ServiceModel reference from this folder:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\System.ServiceModel.dll

It not working again.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is your project Profile78? Check your warnings to see if anything is amiss.